# Action from reducer returns 'undefined'

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I tried to perform my action from `filterSlice`, but it turns to be `undefined`.
I have the slice (**FilterSlice.js**):

```
export const filterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'filter',
    initialState: {
      ...
      minPrice: 0,
      maxPrice: 2147483647,
      ...
    },
    reducers: { 
      adjustPrice: (state, action) => {
          state.minPrice = action.payload.minPrice;
          state.maxPrice = action.payload.maxPrice;
      }
    },
   ...
```

Exported action from that slice:

```
export const { adjustPrice } = filterSlice.reducer;
```

In another file I'm trying to dispatch that action:

```
import { ... adjustPrice } from '../features/filter/filterSlice';
...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
const handleApplyClick = () => dispatch(adjustPrice(100, 1000));
```

And it causes an error, because of for some reason `adjustPrice()` is undefined.

**TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
handleApplyClick
C:/diploma/client/src/components/PriceRangePanel.js:84
84 |  const handleApplyClick = () => dispatch(adjustPrice(100, 1000));
| ^  85 |**

Funnily enough it's perfectly fine in Redux Devtools:
[Redux Devtools example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z08tp.png)

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is

```js
export const { adjustPrice } = filterSlice.actions;
```

not `filterSlice.reducer`